# SSL in python3 with HTTPServer

Tags: ssl, python-3.x, https

I found here a (apparently-)working HTTPS server for python 2: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442473-simple-http-server-supporting-ssl-secure-communica/?c=15536

I'm trying to port it in python3 but I have no good results. This is my code:

```
from socketserver import BaseServer
import string,cgi,time
from os import curdir, sep
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import ssl
import os # os. path
import socket

class SecureHTTPServer(HTTPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass):
        BaseServer.__init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass)
        ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
        #server.pem's location (containing the server private key and
        #the server certificate).
        fpem = 'certificate1.pem'
        ctx.load_verify_locations(fpem)
        self.socket = ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(self.address_family,
                                                        self.socket_type))
        self.server_bind()
        self.server_activate()


class SecureHTTPRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def setup(self):
        self.connection = self.request
        self.rfile = socket._fileobject(self.request, "rb", self.rbufsize)
        self.wfile = socket._fileobject(self.request, "wb", self.wbufsize)
    def do_GET(self):
        print('get recieved!');
        self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

def test(HandlerClass = SecureHTTPRequestHandler,
         ServerClass = SecureHTTPServer):
    server_address = ('', 1443) # (address, port)
    httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)
    sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
    print ("Serving HTTPS on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "...")
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

When I run it I get no errors, but when I connect to localhost:1443 (with https) I get no response and the `print('get recieved!');` is't triggered.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found another (simpler) solution here: http://www.piware.de/2011/01/creating-an-https-server-in-python/

This is my working porting to `python3`:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer,SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from socketserver import BaseServer
import ssl

httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 1443), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='certificate.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: I don't think you need `BaseServer` here.

Comment: Thanks, this mostly worked for my but I had to add the parameter for my private key (keyfile='private.pem') in the wrap_socket call.

Answer (score 13):

Since Python 3.7 ssl.wrap_socket is deprecated, use SSLContext.wrap_socket instead:

check: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket

and since version 3.10: SSLContext without protocol argument is deprecated.

check: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext

```
from http.server import HTTPServer,SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl

httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 1443), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
# Since version 3.10: SSLContext without protocol argument is deprecated. 
# sslctx = ssl.SSLContext()
sslctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
sslctx.check_hostname = False # If set to True, only the hostname that matches the certificate will be accepted
sslctx.load_cert_chain(certfile='certificate.pem', keyfile="private.pem")
httpd.socket = sslctx.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Thanks! With your code now we can use sslcontext.
A simple fix: ssl_ctx.wrap_sockert -> sslctx.wrapsocket

Comment: `ssl.SSLContext()` is now also deprecated. Use `ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)` instead