# How to create a Python HTTPS Webserver using Let's Encrypt certificate?

Tags: python, https, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've finished my Python Bot for telegram to send HTML5 games through the chat, thanks to the help of this community!
Unfortunately it seems that in order for the bot to fetch the score, I need to actually set up a HTTP server within the bot to do so. As it seems through my research, I can't seem to figure out how to create a server in python with ssl, without it being self signed (since it will give a blank page when the user clicks to play the game).

I bought a domain and it's already set up with my VPS IP adress, altough I have a ssl certificate for Apache...

Could someone help me set this up? Since sending and unsecured HTTP connection or a self-signed one will result in a blank page within the app...

Thank you very much!

Edit1: Bot Code:

```
import configparser, threading, requests, json, re, time, sys
from uuid import uuid4

from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram import InlineQueryResultGame, ParseMode, InputTextMessageContent
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, InlineQueryHandler, CommandHandler, CallbackContext
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler


def error_callback(update, context):
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)

class Global:
    def __init__(self):
        return

class GameHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args)

    def do_GET(self):
        if "#" in self.path:
            self.path = self.path.split("#")[0]
        if "?" in self.path:
            (route, params) = self.path.split("?")
        else:
            route = self.path
            params = ""
        route = route[1:]
        params = params.split("&")
        if route in Global.games:
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(open(route+'.html', 'rb').read())
        elif route == "setScore":
            params = {}
            for item in self.path.split("?")[1].split("&"):
                if "=" in item:
                    pair = item.split("=")
                    params[pair[0]] = pair[1]
            print(params)
            if "imid" in params:
                Global.bot.set_game_score(params["uid"], params["score"], inline_message_id=params["imid"]) 
            else:
                Global.bot.set_game_score(params["uid"], params["score"], message_id=params["mid"], chat_id=params["cid"])
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b'Set score')
        else:
            self.send_response(404)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b'Invalid game!')

def start(update, context):
    Global.bot.send_game(update.message.chat_id, Global.featured)

def error(update, context):
    print(update, error)

def button(update, context):
    print(update)
    query = update.callback_query
    game = query.game_short_name
    uid = str(query.from_user.id)
    if query.message:
        mid = str(query.message.message_id)
        cid = str(query.message.chat.id)
        url = "http://" + Global.host + ":"+Global.port + "/" + game + "?uid="+uid+"&mid="+mid+"&cid="+cid
    else:
        imid = update.callback_query.inline_message_id
        url = "http://" + Global.host + ":"+Global.port + "/" + game + "?uid="+uid+"&imid="+imid
    print(url)
    Global.bot.answer_callback_query(query.id, text=game, url=url)

def inlinequery(update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    results = []
    for game in Global.games:
        if query.lower() in game.lower():
            results.append(InlineQueryResultGame(id=str(uuid4()),game_short_name=game))
    Global.update.inline_query.answer(results)

def main():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    token = config['DEFAULT']['API_KEY']
    Global.games = config['DEFAULT']['GAMES'].split(',')
    Global.host = config['DEFAULT']['HOST']
    Global.port = config['DEFAULT']['PORT']
    Global.featured = config['DEFAULT']['FEATURED']
    updater = Updater(token=token, use_context=True)

    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    dp.add_handler(InlineQueryHandler(inlinequery))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
    dp.add_error_handler(error)
    Global.bot = updater.bot

    print("Polling telegram")
    updater.start_polling()

    print("Starting http server")   
    http = HTTPServer((Global.host, int(Global.port)), GameHTTPRequestHandler)
    http.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Code inside the HTML5 Game, related to the score:

```
function gameOver() {
            isGameOver = true;
            clearInterval(gameInterval);

            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const uid = urlParams.get('uid');
            const mid = urlParams.get('mid');
            const cid = urlParams.get('cid');
            const imid = urlParams.get('imid');
            if (imid) {
                const request = new Request(`/setScore?uid=${uid}&imid=${imid}&score=${score}`);
                fetch(request).then(response => console.log("set score"));
            }
            else {
                const request = new Request(`/setScore?uid=${uid}&mid=${mid}&cid=${cid}&score=${score}`);
                fetch(request).then(response => console.log("set score"));
            }
        }
```

Original Bot by [Mark Powers](https://github.com/Mark-Powers/telegram-arcade)

Comment: You would typically put something like Apache or Nginx in front of your Python script, and use that frontend tool for ssl termination. There are lots of docs out there showing how to configure either with a LetsEncrypt certificate.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what do you mean by putting Apache in front of my Python script? I'm still learning and so I still lack some of the basic concepts... If I did that, would the script be able to execute do_get functions that I'm using with the SimpleHTTTPserver?

Comment: Please try to clarify the connection of the HTTP server in question and the bots functionality, e.g. what exactly do you mean by "for the bot to fetch the score"? Probably also explain how you host the HTML5 game. It may also be helpful if you gave a short overview of how your bot is built - so far you've tagged `python` and `python-telegram-bot` but didn't tell us anything about how you use those.

Comment: @CallMeStag I'm sorry for not being more objective with my questions and not providing the code! Initially I wanted to host the game in a Apache Server, so I routed the URL to that host. But I couldn't figuire out a way to get Apache to send the score back to the bot after the game has ended. If I host it within the same directory of the bot, with SimpleHTTPServer , this server is able to send it directly to the bot, and so it displays the score.

Comment: I understand that making the `set_game_score` request directly from your HTML game (which is hosted independently from your bot) *would* be an acceptable solution for you? And in the case where you have the SimpleHTTPServer set up in python: Does it listen to traffic directly (i.e. posting to your-domain.org directly posts to that server) or is there e.g. some reverse-proxy step in between?

Comment: Yes I guess it would, but I don't know how I would do that... Yes, it does listen to the traffic directly! I have been trying to find a solution to a simple way to get the score with no positive results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some clarifications about the question the comments, let me try to make some comments. This is probably far from a ready-to-use solution and more some hints on what to look for.

The ultimate goal is to trigger a `setGameScore` request from a HTML5 + JS webpage, while having that webpage properly SSL encrypted. That page can either be hosted independently of the bot, in which case the JS code should make the request itself (method 1 below), or is hosted via a python-based webserver within the same script as the bot (methods 2 + 3 below), in which case the goals would be to

1. have the JS code make a request to that webserver, so that the webserver does the request and
2. ensure SSL encryption so that the website can be integrated into Telegams game setup.

### Method 1: Let the website do it directly

Currently your JS code does something like

```
const request = new Request(`/setScore?uid=${uid}&imid=${imid}&score=${score}`);
fetch(request).then(response => console.log("set score"));
```

My knowledge of JS is limited, but judging by sources like [this](https://javascript.info/fetch) it seems like

```
fetch("https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/setGameScore?...").then(response => console.log("set score"));
```

should already do the trick

### Method 2: Figure out SSL with `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`

This seems to be a more general topic. E.g. I found these similar looking questions:

- [SSL in python3 with HTTPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429648)
- [How to set up a simple https server using a Cloudflare SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56352373)

### Method 3: Use a reverse proxy to handle the SSL stuff

I.e. make the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` listen to "localhost" and have Apache/Nginx forward traffic to the correct port. Inspiration for this basically comes from [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks#using-nginx-with-one-domainport-for-all-bots). In this case, encrypting apache/nginx with letsencrypt should be rather straightforward.

Comment: I just read this and... it's amazing! I'm going to research and try the methods you just proposed! Thank you for the time you have put into my problem, let's hope it works!